# System of offers with multiple offers and products

Tags: php, mysql, business-logic

I am developing a system of offers and I came up with the following problem:

If I have an offer that buying the "product A" and "Product B" I paid 10% less, I can register as a new offer such a product like Coke, putting the price discounting 10%, ok, but the problem is, if the user select the product A and product B I want to convert it to a discount, ie, selecting the products that generate the discount, the user takes the discount.

My solution is:
I could make a table with the products and set the type of product as normal and promotion, if the type of product is promotion, will have a table associated with the products (in this case the product A and product B), but If I have 10 offers, I need to verify each product to ensure it participates in the promotion, I think soo slow.

Sorry my English, if you don't understand me, leave a comment. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup the products table as normal. Then set up a special offers table and a table for the products included in each offer.

### Products Table

product_id

product_name

### Offers Table:

offer_id

percent_off

### Products_In_Offer Table

offer_id

product_id

Comment: Correct, but, when user select Product A and Product B, how I can search over 100 offers what is the offer that match the selection he made?